# How to get absolute url without root?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, uri

I have this root: http://localhost/foldername/about

I would like to get only the `/about` part.

How can I do this?

Comment: take the last index of `/` and use `Substring()` on the root string with the last index of `/`?

Comment: also a nice solution :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be of help to you:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths

Comment: Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath this is what i was looking for just removing the ~

Answer (score 7):

Use [Uri.Segments Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx)

> The Segments property returns an array of strings containing the
>   "segments" (substrings) that form the URI's absolute path. The first
>   segment is obtained by parsing the absolute path from its first
>   character until you reach a slash (/) or the end of the path. Each
>   additional segment begins at the first character after the preceding
>   segment, and terminates with the next slash or the end of the path. (A
>   URI's absolute path contains everything after the host and port and
>   before the query and fragment.)

```
Uri uriAddress1 = new Uri("http://localhost/foldername/about");
Console.WriteLine("The parts are {0}, {1}, {2}", uriAddress1.Segments[0], 
                  uriAddress1.Segments[1], uriAddress1.Segments[2]);
```

See more about [Uri Class MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)